# This code isnt setting certain values

Tags: t-sql

So I'm writing some proceedures for tsql to get a group project back off the ground, and am trying to write something to create user profiles with salted passwords. However, when I run this code, the values for @seedno and @saltval never get set, so my hashed password ends up with a null value. Is there anyone who can help?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateCustomerAccount]
    @companyName nvarchar (50),
    @emailAddress nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar (100),
    @Addr1  nvarchar (50),
    @Addr2  nvarchar (50),
    @Addr3  nvarchar (50),
    @postCode nvarchar (11),
    @Telephone NVARCHAR (20),
    @vatNo NVARCHAR (20) 

AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --Declare some variables here
    DECLARE     
        @pwdSalt NVARCHAR (25),
        @Seed INT,                                  /* this is going to store the randomly generated seed we will use to make the salt */
        @CurrentChar CHAR,
        @SaltedPwd NVARCHAR (125),
        @LoopCountVar TINYINT,                      /*because counting is fun, kids :). */
        @Seedno integer,
        @saltval CHAR 




        --Generate a seed using the customers email address and a psuedo random number generator.

        SET @LoopCountVar = 0;

        WHILE @LoopCountVar <= LEN(@emailAddress)
            BEGIN
                SET @CurrentChar = SUBSTRING(@EmailAddress, @LoopCountVar, 1)

                SET @Seedno = (ASCII(@currentChar)*CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10000))

                SET @Seed = @Seed + @Seedno   --Add the integer value of the current character multiplied by a random number between 0 and 100,000 to the seed

                SET @LoopCountVar = @LoopCountVar+1

            END;

    --Now, populate our salt string by inserting random characters using the seed we just created.
    SET @LoopCountVar = 0;

    while @loopCountVar <= 25
    BEGIN
        SET @saltval = CHAR (ROUND((RAND()*94)+32,3))
        SET @pwdSalt = @pwdSalt + @saltval
        SET @LoopCountVar = @LoopCountVar+1 
    END;

    --Time for delicious delicious salted hash
    Set @SaltedPwd = @pwdSalt+@password;

    -- Insert data into table
    Insert into Customer (orgName, Email, AccountPwd, PwdSalt, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, PostCode, TelephoneNo, VATNo)
    VALUES (@companyName, @emailAddress, HASHBYTES('MD5', @SaltedPwd), @pwdSalt, @Addr1, @Addr2, @Addr3, @postCode, @Telephone, @vatNo);
RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a very roundabout way to generate the pwd. 
Anyway in your second loop you are using an unassigned variable, this making the result null

Try this:

```
SET @LoopCountVar = 0;
SET @pwdSalt=''
while @loopCountVar <= 25
BEGIN
    SET @saltval = CHAR (ROUND((RAND()*94)+32,3))
    SET @pwdSalt = @pwdSalt + @saltval
    SET @LoopCountVar = @LoopCountVar+1 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several things to fix. 
First, you are trying to multiply the `ASCII()` function return value, which is an `INT`, to a `VARBINARY(80)` which is the return type of the `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` function.

Second, you are calling the `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10000)` with a parameter length bigger than 8000, which is the maximum of length you can use with this function.

Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/crypt-gen-random-transact-sql) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql) links.
Generally, you can debug your stored procedure body step by step selecting the values of the variables you have inside it prior to doing any calculation.

Comment: Well since the seed is never used, the first loop seems to be a waste of effort anyway.

Comment: Thats fine, the current version uses @seed in the second loop. I forgot it at some point down the line. I changed the line to

`SET @Seedno = (ASCII(@currentChar)*CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2) AS INT))`

Comment: ...and it threw
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure CreateCustomerAccount, Line 62
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

sorry about the doublepost. I haven't used this before and I'm struggling to get used to it.

Comment: Is this after you made the correction I mentioned? setting assigning @pwdsalt before the loop? Anyway, the error seems to come when you try the insert. Check the schema for the table you are inserting into, and check that all varchars are big enough for the inserted values.

Comment: By the way, your second loop is running 26 times, is that on purpose? set the limit to @loopCountVar < 25 to stop after 25 loops

Comment: I fixed it in the end. Turns out I'd not set the salt to the right length on the table. I'm an idiot. Thank you for all of your help